# libre office ls: error initializing month strings 13.04

Tags: libreoffice

I'm trying to start libre office writer up, but it doesn't do anything. I started it from the terminal as root and it showed me this:

ls: error initializing month strings
/usr/bin/libreoffice: 49: cd: can't cd to lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 �../lib/libreoffice/program
/usr/bin/libreoffice: 156: exec: /usr/bin/oosplash: not found

Is there a known workaround for this, becouse my good friend google couldn't help, and i also couldn't find an answer on this forum.

Ty guys

Answer (score 0):

Ugly hack: as root edit the starter script eg: nano /usr/bin/libreoffice

Search for section marked with "# resolve installation directory". There you find a line with an ls command, add the "--time-style=iso " option for ls. The fixed line should look like:

sd_res=`ls --time-style=iso -l "$sd_basename" | sed "s/.*$sd_basename -> //g"`

You may have to fix more than this invocation of ls. This is a temporary fix, as a new version of libreoffice will overwrite the statup script, so you have to do again if the problem still will be there. Also you can check, if you type "ls -l" into a terminal and no error message then the problem is solved.